# Schema Permissions in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: permissions, schema, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 2 Schema and 3 generic users to access the data from my DB

```
Schema : EMSMaster and EMSTransactional
Users : BN_USER, MBN_USER and SUPER_ADMIN
```

My permissions should be like

```
BN_USER  - select on EMSMaster 
       select, insert and update on EMSTransactional

MBN_USER - select, insert, update on EMSMaster
       select, insert, update and Delete on EMSTransactional
```

Is there any way to give this kind of permissions on Schema? Please suggest me some good way to implement this kind of permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GRANT SELECT ON schema :: EMSMaster TO BN_USER 
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON schema :: EMSTransactional TO BN_USER 

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON schema :: EMSMaster TO MBN_USER 
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON schema :: EMSTransactional TO MBN_USER
```